# Comparing Attribute in Laravel Eloquent Request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a controller function where I would like to compare a field in a model to an attribute of that model and use it in a `where` like so below, is it possible?

```php
$ticketsOpen = Ticket::where([
                 ['balance','>','paidBalance'],
                 ['bill_to', $customer->id]
                 ])
                  ->whereNotIn('shipment_billing_status', [2,3])
                  ->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
```

In this case, the 'paidBalance' up above refers to this in the model:

```php
public function getPaidBalanceAttribute(){
    $paid = $this->paymentDistributions->pluck('amount');
    $paidBalance = $paid->sum();
    return $paidBalance;
}
```

And the `paymentDistributions` refers above that to this:

```php
 public function paymentDistributions(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Payments_Distribution', 'ticket_id','id');
    }
```

Or is there a better way of going around this? I'm just trying to filter down the tickets that have a balance greater than what's been paid or have no payments toward the ticket at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use an [Eloquent Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) inside the [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries).

The Query Builder prepares an statement for your **database** (which is executed when invoking the `get` method) while the accessor is performed by your **web server** (eg nginx) after having created your Model from the data retrieved.

The easiest way to solve it would be by performing a `filter` on your customer tickets after having retrieved the data.

```
$ticketsOpen = Ticket::where('bill_to', $customer->id)
    ->whereNotIn('shipment_billing_status', [2,3])
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get()
    ->filter(function (Ticket $ticket){
        return $ticket->balance > $ticket->paidBalance;
    });
```

Keep in mind you may want to [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) your payment distributions depending on the amount of data (`->with('paymentDistributions')`) and also include a call to `->values()` at the end should you have to reset your indexes (since filtering preserves them aka leaves any gaps).